# How to prevent Flurry change orientation of my activity?

Tags: android, flurry, landscape-portrait

One of my activities in my app has an `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` attribute in the manifest, as I don't want it to change orientation. 
I'm trying to integrate Flurry like this:
in onStart:

```
FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "api_key");
FlurryAgent.initializeAds(this);
FrameLayout adsFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutAdsContent);
FlurryAgent.getAd(this, "BannerTop-1", adsFrameLayout, FlurryAdSize.BANNER_BOTTOM, 0);
```

in inStop:

```
FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
```

and in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

What happens is that Flurry lets the activity to change orientation (when device is turned ti landscape). if I don't run the code in onStart the activity doesn't change its orientation.

thanks in advance,
Amitos80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research i found that this can't be done. flurry overrides my configuration and enables the screen to change orientation to landscape. if someone ever find a solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add: android:orientation="vertical" to the layout xml?